# PDF of $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2$ with $x_i \sim N(\mu_i,1)$

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, chi-squared-distribution, non-central

What is the probability distribution function of the random variable $X$

$X=x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2, \tag{1}$

where $x_i$ are independent normally distributed variables $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,1)$?

**What I tried**

$X$ can also be expressed as the difference of two noncentral $\chi^2(k,\lambda)$ distributed variables:

$X=\chi^2(2,x_1^2+x_2^2)-\chi^2(2,x_3^2+x_4^2)=\chi^2(2,\lambda_1)-\chi^2(2,\lambda_2).\tag{2}$

If we try to derive the pdf by the characteristic function of the noncentral $\chi^2$-distribution we encounter an integral of the form

$$f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm exp}\left(i t z\right)}{3t^2+1}{\rm exp}\left(\frac{i t a+ t^2 b}{3t^2+1}\right){\rm d}t\\
{\rm with }\,\, z\in \mathbb{R},a\in \mathbb{R},b\in \mathbb{R}_{< 0}, i^2=-1,\tag{3}$$

that I could not solve.

In this forum I found only this related [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/266388/269684) however it is unclear if the answer given there is applicable here, or if the answer is right.

Comment: I think because we have $y_i^2 \sim -x_i^2$ and these are independent then the distribution should be noncentral $\chi^2(4, \sum_i \mu_i^2)$, but i'm not 100% sure on that

Comment: @bdeonovic That cannot possibly be correct, because $X$ has positive probability of being negative whereas that is never the case for any $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: yep I just realized my own stupidity, need to get more coffee. I appreciate the bluntness of your correction though @whuber, in contrast to your typical gentle leading question :)

Comment: @bdeonovic Sorry.  I make those kinds of mistakes all the time--I blame haste ;-).

Comment: The moment-generating function method fails, here, unfortunately. While you can get the mgf of $X,$ it does not appear possible to invert it (using the inverse Laplace Transform, say, with negated $t$), to get back to the pdf. I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: You can numerically compute it / plot it in R using `distr::plot(distr::Chisq(2, 2) - distr::Chisq(2, 2), to.draw.arg='d')`.

Comment: Also the characteristic function of $X - X'$ where $X,X'$ are independent is $\|f\|$, where $f$ is the chf of $X$, so you can get it explicitly from the [chf of non-central chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).

Answer (score 6):

As noted by the OP, this problem can be simplified to the difference in  two independent noncentral $\chi^2$ random variables:

$$X=X_1^2+X_2^2-X_3^2-X_4^2=Z_1-Z_2$$

where $Z_i\sim \chi^2(2,\lambda_i)$, $\lambda_1=\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2$, $\lambda_2=\mu_3^2+\mu_4^2$ and $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent.

Because your profile shows you have access to *Mathematica*, here is how one can find any desired moment of $Z$:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[z1 - z2,
   {z1 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ1],
    z2 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ2]}];
Mean[dist]
(* λ1-λ2 *)
Variance[dist]
(* 4 (2+λ1+λ2) *)
Skewness[dist]
(* (3 (λ1-λ2))/(2+λ1+λ2)^(3/2) *)
Kurtosis[dist]
(* 3 (8+8 λ1+λ1^2+8 λ2+2 λ1 λ2+ *)
CentralMoment[dist, 5]
(* 960 (4 λ1+λ1^2-4 λ2-λ2^2) *)
CentralMoment[dist, 6]
(* 960 (48+72 λ1+24 λ1^2+λ1^3+72 λ2+24 λ1 λ2+3 λ1^2 λ2+24 λ2^2+3 λ1 λ2^2+λ2^3) *)
CentralMoment[dist, 7]
(* 40320 (24 λ1+12 λ1^2+λ1^3-24 λ2+λ1^2 λ2-12 λ2^2-λ1 λ2^2-λ2^3) *)
```

Other than maybe some special cases, it is unlikely that there's a nice closed-form for the density of $Z$.  But to estimate the density numerically (and perform a check with a large random sample), consider the following for $\lambda_1=\mu_1^2+\mu_2^2=1^2+2^2=5$ and $\lambda_2=\mu_3+\mu_4=1^2+\sqrt{2}^2=3$:

```
pdf1 = PDF[NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ1], z1][[1, 1, 1]] // FunctionExpand
```

[image: Density of Z1]

```
pdf2 = PDF[NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ2], z1 - z][[1, 1, 1]] // FunctionExpand
```

[image: Density of Z1 - Z]

```
pdfz[z_?NumericQ, λ1_?NumericQ, λ2_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[1/2 E^(1/2 (-z1 - λ1)) BesselI[0, Sqrt[z1] Sqrt[λ1]]*
            1/2 E^(1/2 (z - z1 - λ2)) BesselI[0, Sqrt[-z + z1] Sqrt[λ2]],
  {z1, Max[0, z], ∞}]

(* Check on a specific example *)
parms = {μ1 -> 1, μ2 -> 2, μ3 -> 1, μ4 -> Sqrt[2]};

(* Distribution of Z *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[z1 - z2,
  {z1 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, μ1^2 + μ2^2],
   z2 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, μ3^2 + μ4^2]}] /. parms;

(* Random sample from Z *)
zz = RandomVariate[dist, 1000000];

(* Plot density and density histogram *)
m = Mean[dist];
s = StandardDeviation[dist];
Show[Histogram[zz, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Z", "Density"}]],
 Plot[pdfz[z, μ1^2 + μ2^2 /. parms, μ3^2 + μ4^2 /. parms], {z, m - 4 s, m + 4 s}]]
```

[image: Density and density histogram]

Comment: What is the advantage of this method compared to eq.3?

Comment: (a) As there is likely no nice closed-form for (3) both approaches need to use a numerical approximation.  (b) (3) requires dealing with $i$ and not all software packages can deal with that, (c) Even in *Mathematica* you'd need to use the `Chop` function to get rid of "little imaginary bits" left over from numerical imprecision, (d)  $a$ and $b$ are not defined as of yet.  (And, yes, (3) is a "compact closed-form" but not easily evaluated in this case.  I wish it were otherwise.)

Comment: Actually, the issue with $i$ in (3) can be removed and things become much more numerically stable.  I'll add that as a separate answer in the next few days - unless someone else wants to do that.  Still the density needs to be determined numerically.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the inverse Fourier transform approach you've labeled as equation (3).  (Again, I've used *Mathematica* as your profile indicates you have access to it and it does all of the algebraic manipulations for me.)

```
(* Characteristic functions of Z1 and -Z2 *)
cf1 = CharacteristicFunction[NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ1], t]
cf2 = CharacteristicFunction[NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ2], -t]
(* Characteristic function of Z = Z1 - Z2 *)
cf = cf1 cf2 // Simplify
```

$$\frac{e^{t \left(\frac{\text{$\lambda $2}}{-2 t+i}-\frac{\text{$\lambda $1}}{2 t+i}\right)}}{4 t^2+1}$$

```
(* Determine integrand for the inverse Fourier transform *)
(* https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104491/how-to-find-a-density-from-a-characteristic-function *)
(* Drop the imaginary term as it will integrate to zero *)
integrand = ComplexExpand[ReIm[Exp[-I z t] cf1 cf2]][[1]]/(2 π) // Together // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{2 t^2 (\text{$\lambda $1}+\text{$\lambda $2})}{4 t^2+1}} \cos \left(\frac{t \left(-\text{$\lambda $1}+\text{$\lambda $2}+4 t^2 z+z\right)}{4 t^2+1}\right)}{8 \pi  t^2+2 \pi }$$

```
(* Define pdf function using numerical integration as there is likely no closed-form solution *)
pdf[z_?NumericQ, λ1_?NumericQ, λ2_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(E^(-((2 t^2 (λ1 + λ2))/(1 + 4 t^2))) Cos[(t (z + 4 t^2 z - λ1 + λ2))/(1 + 4 t^2)])/
  (2 π + 8 π t^2), {t, -∞, ∞}]

(* Set parameters *)
parms = {λ1 -> 5, λ2 -> 3};

(* Determine mean and standard deviation of Z for setting plotting limits *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[z1 - z2, 
  {z1 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ1],
   z2 \[Distributed] NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[2, λ2]}] /. parms;
m = Mean[dist];
s = StandardDeviation[dist];

(* Generate a large random sample as a check *)
zz = RandomVariate[dist, 100000];

(* Plot density and histogram *)
Show[Histogram[zz, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF",
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Z", "Density"}],
  Plot[Evaluate[pdf[z, λ1 /. parms, λ2 /. parms]], {z, m - 4 s, m + 4 s}]]
```

[image: Density and density histogram]